# React CRA production build `npm run build` without a .git/ folder gives a ugly warning?

Tags: reactjs, git, create-react-app

I am copying my web project’s source  code which was created using React CRA into a docker container to do its production build.

I am deliberately not copying over the project’s `.git` folder in the hope  of shaving a few seconds off the long build time.

It builds ok but I get ugly warning from CRA

```
CI='' npm run build
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
Creating an optimized production build...
```

I tried doing a `git init` but it gives a different git warning.

Is there an elegant way to avoid the CRA code which I run logging this misleading & ugly warning ?

I know of https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9502 but that is focused on the create stage. It's the production build I care about.